# XRD experiment: how to interpret data and solve crystal structure from 2theta vs intensity values

Tags: spectroscopy, software, crystallography, x-ray-diffraction

I have just performed an XRD (X ray diffraction) experiment (powder), but the XRD machine I have used is not able to describe crystal data, I have $2\theta$ and intensity in arbitrary units in a UXD file. My knowledge in XRD is limited, only conceptual, so I don't know exactly to solve a structure by manual calculations, I find these procedure to be very difficult. My question is if there is any software I can use to solve the XRD data into a crystal CIF file, so I can interrogate the database COD (Crystallography Online Database) to obtain my molecular model. The compound I have synthetized is not a novel/unknown product, so it is possible to find it in databases (it is Graphene Oxide).

Comment: You need just the unit cell parameters, not a CIF file.

Comment: And how do I determine unit cell parameters from XRD file? Or I need to know them from another source?

Comment: You can find an example calculation here https://chemistry-maths-book.com/chapter-9/Fourier-2D-Diffraction.html  as well as an explanation of x-ray diffraction in crystals

Comment: If your data is digitised you can use Rietveld refinement.